# Google Cloud Breakglass Role

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-iam

I need to create a role for highly privileged access that can be provisioned rapidly and deprovisioned after x amount of time. My initial thought was to use the following to accomplish this:

Have service account A assume the role of the privileged service account B, but I hit a few snags. First, the documentation only allows the use of POST, and I’m not allowed any external access to my environment. Second, I can print an access token, but how do I then impersonate the second account. Third, I need to be able to print the token information to verify TTL. I’m curious as to whether this can all be done from gcloud? I know there are some Python libraries, etc. but I more need to make this a bash command, as stated before, I have very stringent oversight, even on my external jumphost.

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You can create temporary credentials (Access Token) from your authenticated account or by specifying a service account. These credentials are valid by default for 3600 seconds. To verify or display the details of an Access Token requires calling a Google endpoint which I am not sure you can do from your statement `I’m not allowed any external access`.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your response. It appears that this can also be accomplished by using the impersonate-service-account command in gcloud. For example, I would like to allow a privileged user to authenticate to a service account with no permissions, and then assume the abilities of the second service account to deploy resources, access reports, etc.